# How do you initialise a std::unique_ptr to a reference

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

With raw pointers I can do:

```
int x = 10;
int* y = &x;

x = 20;
std::cout << *y; //prints 20
```

However, Im struggling to emulate the same behaviour with `std::unique_ptr`. Ive tried:

```
int x = 10;

std::unique_ptr<int> y = std::make_unique(&x); //doesnt compile
std::unique_ptr<int> y = std::make_unique<int>(&x); //doesnt compile
std::unique_ptr<int&> y = std::make_unique(x); //doesnt compile
std::unique_ptr<int> y = std::make_unique<int&>(&x); //doesnt compile

std::unique_ptr<int> y = std::make_unique<int>(x); //compiles but prints y = 10, which is not the desired behaviour
```

Im sure there is a way, so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That makes sense, all this talk of not using raw pointers has got to me. shrug. Thanks :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using raw pointers in general, as long as they are not used for dealing with ownership semantics. What is not recommended anymore is using `new`/`delete` directly, in lieu of standard containers and smart pointers that provide stronger ownership semantics. Two different things.

Comment: Note that if you program in C++ by trial and error, you're going to have a bad time. Undefined Behaviour is lurking in the dark, waiting to pounce on the unsuspecting programmer. Documentation is your friend.

Comment: @alterigel I was reading cpp reference, but it was driving me insane because it didnt show how to initialise a unique ptr from a reference! doh ... you cant do that so it isnt on cpp reference. should have read the small text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unique_ptr` is about managing the lifetime of dynamically allocated memory.

That is to say

```
std::unique_ptr<int> y = std::make_unique<int>(x);
```

says allocate memory for an integer, **copy** the value of x into it and when y goes out of scope please release that memory.

In your example, you are not interested in managing the lifetime of the allocated storage, you just want another "view" of what's stored for x. It's not what `unique_ptr` is designed to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is no dynamic allocation in the 1st code, so no need to try to emulate it with `unique_ptr` at all.

`unique_ptr` manages a pointer to an object that is allocated with `new` , and will `delete` that object when the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope. You can't make `unique_ptr` act as a reference to an external object it doesn't own.

That being said, if you did want two smart pointers to refer to the same object in memory, then use `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr`, eg:

```cpp
#include <memory>

auto x = std::make_shared<int>(10);
auto y = x;

*x = 20;
std::cout << *y; //prints 20
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/sxQevY)

Comment: You could have the unique ptr "manage" the address, and give it a noop deleter. Pointless, but it does what OP is asking

Comment: @AndyG in that situation, it is not really any better than a `std::reference_wrapper`.